# pg node + POSTGRES column name does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am using pg and nodejs to make a simple backend DB. When I try and query the table, I am getting an error that says that the column name does not exist. Yet, when I perform a SQL query to find all the column names in the table, it shows columns with the same name.

This is what I use to query the table with the column field:

```
const query = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = $1', [email]);
```

and this is the error message from performing that query:

```
error: column "email" does not exist
```

And this is the response from looking up the columns of the table in the database:

```
{
  table_catalog: 'recipe-book',
  table_schema: 'public',
  table_name: 'user',
  column_name: 'email',
  ordinal_position: 2,
  column_default: null,
  is_nullable: 'NO',
  data_type: 'character varying',
  character_maximum_length: 255,
  character_octet_length: 1020,
  numeric_precision: null,
  numeric_precision_radix: null,
  numeric_scale: null,
  datetime_precision: null,
  interval_type: null,
  interval_precision: null,
  character_set_catalog: null,
  character_set_schema: null,
  character_set_name: null,
  collation_catalog: null,
  collation_schema: null,
  collation_name: null,
  domain_catalog: null,
  domain_schema: null,
  domain_name: null,
  udt_catalog: 'recipe-book',
  udt_schema: 'pg_catalog',
  udt_name: 'varchar',
  scope_catalog: null,
  scope_schema: null,
  scope_name: null,
  maximum_cardinality: null,
  dtd_identifier: '2',
  is_self_referencing: 'NO',
  is_identity: 'NO',
  identity_generation: null,
  identity_start: null,
  identity_increment: null,
  identity_maximum: null,
  identity_minimum: null,
  identity_cycle: 'NO',
  is_generated: 'NEVER',
  generation_expression: null,
  is_updatable: 'YES'
},
```

I've used pg and node in this way before and have never seen this error, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a `user` function in postgres showing the current user on the db.

so in your case, it is selecting the postgres user table instead of your own user table. Although you specified your DB in the connection setting, the current user will be retrieved.

To get rid of it, either rename the table or use double quote to indicate the differences.

```sql
const query = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE email = $1`, [email]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be [`pg_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-user.html), not plain `user`?

Comment: Done some digging. [`user` is not a table, it's a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75551/returning-rows-in-postgresql-with-a-table-called-user).

Comment: Yes. you are right. it is displaying the current logged in user. Will change my answer.